# Node JS infinite wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a simple program that fetches data from a database. But when connected, infinite loading occurs.

router

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('/music', '', musicController.getMusicList)
})
```

controller

```
'getMusicList' : async () => {
    try {
        var music_list = await musicModel.getMusicList()
        return music_list
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

model

```
'getMusicList' : (req, res) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            await dbcon.query("SELECT * FROM music", (error, results) => {
                console.log(error)
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    resolve(results)
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: thanks! i solved myself

Answer (score 0):

i solved my self

i changed my router source code

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let list = await musicController.getMusicList()
  res.render('/index', {list : list})
})
```